# Jquery - How to trigger $('#myForm').submit(function()

Tags: jquery, triggers, submit

how can i trigger this function without using the form submit?

```
$('#myForm').submit(function()
{ ....
```

Comment: when do you want to trigger the function, on page load? on some click etc?

Comment: i want to trigger when i click on a normal button

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You could try -

```
$('#myForm').trigger('submit');
```

Working demo - http://jsfiddle.net/ipr101/KvwMb/1/

Comment: ok, the code works in your example, so it must be a bug in my code.

Answer (score 6):

You can directly use something like this

```
$('#button1').click(function(){
    $('#search').submit();
});
```

Or you can use it from any javascript code. Which will trigger your `$('#myForm').submit(function(){.....` function code.

Answer (score 2):

```
return false;
```

adding this to function will stop the form submitting.

Or if you want to call function on a different event put the function in an appropriate event handler (a non-submit button's click?)

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="button" id="btn" value="click">
```

jquery

```
     $(function(){
        $('#myForm').submit(function()
             { ....});

         $("#btn").click(function(){
         $('#myForm').trigger('submit');
        });
     });
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to dig it from DOM data. But, let me tell you, its not recommended. Try this,

```
var form = $('#myForm');
var data = form.data();
var events = data.events;
```

If the handler function is attached to form 'submit', it will be present as,

```
var submit_list = events.submit;
```

Now, if all goes well, at best you can get `submit_list` as list of all the handler objects attached to submit event of form.

**Shortcut:**
Assuming you have one and only one handler attached to submit event for `#myForm`,

```
$('#myForm').data().events.submit[0].handler
```

is your function.

Play with `data()`, but remember its not recommended. Happy Coding.