# How trigger on submit function manually?

Tags: javascript, jquery, eventtrigger

I have submit function that is triggered on submit button inside of the form. Here is example:

```
$(document.body).on('submit', '#myfrm', submitFrm);
    function submitFrm(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var frmData = $(this).serialize();

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'ajax/form_data.cfm',
            data: frmData
        }).done(function(data){
            //data saved
        }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
            alert('Error: '+errorThrown);
        });
    }
}
```

Now I would like to trigger `submitFrm()` function from another function like this:

```
function Cancel() {
   submitFrm();
}
```

This will throw an error that `e` doesn't exist. I guess that submit needs to be triggered manually. Is there a way to do that with JQuery?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jquery - How to trigger $('#myForm').submit(function()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7317223/jquery-how-to-trigger-myform-submitfunction)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error happens because you are calling `submitFrm` without passing the event (`e`). The event argument is passed by JavaScript to the function when the `submit` event occurs. If you call the function manually you do not have the event.

What you can do is to use JQuery to get a reference to the form element (`$('#myfrm')`) and trigger the submit event on hit:

```
function Cancel() {
  $('#myfrm').submit();
}
```

In this way the submit event is triggered on the form and the `submitFrm` handler is called with the event in input.

Answer (score 1):

```
function Cancel() {
    $('#myfrm').submit();
}
```

according to https://api.jquery.com/submit/